# Call action via button with OdooV12

Tags: xml, qweb, odoo-12

I'm an Odoo developer and my issue is i wanna call an action from template into xml file.
For Odoo docs/guide is so poor, so i need help to do something great.

Thanks

```
<!-- This is my action declaration into '''views/action_views.xml''' -->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_show_something">
    <field name="name">Wanna show you something</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="view_type">tree</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
     .........
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>

<!-- Right now, this is my template file '''views/template.xml''' -->
<template id="my_template_button_view">
 <a role="button" type="object" name="action_show_something" string="Call the action !!!" />Call the action</a>
</template>

<!-- The button is visible but the action's not working ...... -->
```

Class ProductTemplate(models.Model):

```
  _inherit = '''product.template'''
  def action_show_something(self):
      view_id = self.env.ref('mymodule_to_show.action_show_something').read()[0]
      return {
       'name':      _(view_id.name) if view_id else '',
       'type':      view_id.type if view_id else '',
       'view_type': view_id.view_type if view_id else '',
       'view_mode': view_id.view_mode if view_id else '',
       'res_model': view_id.res_model if view_id else '',
       'target':    'new',
      }
```

Comment: The both (record and/or python function) does not work !!!!

Comment: Is required JavaScript file to do that !!!

Comment: Have you tried `type="action" name=%(action_show_something)d` yet?

Comment: <a type="action" name="%(action_show_something)d"
      id="action_show_something" class="btn btn-secondary mt8 rounded-circle"
      style="color:white !important;font-weight:bold;"
      string="Call something">Call something</a> does not working!!!

Comment: Does not works. Button still visible but dialog popup ain't active when i try to click the button. With button tag as tagname, the action is not the correct (it call another action_name).